# Debugging android device over the Internet

Tags: android, remote-debugging

I am looking for a way to debug a device remotely over the Internet.

I am getting a lot of bug reports from my users which I can't even reproduce. It would be easy to solve them if I could debug the device over the Internet as if it were connected to my PC.
Is this possible?

I heard about debugging over wifi in local network, maybe there is similar way to achieve it over the Internet?

Answer (score 6):

It is possible to setup Android device for debugging over Internet, however it requires USB connection to enable it or root access on the device. In addition to that you will have to setup port forwarding to device to accept incoming ADB connections from the the Internet. It hardly can help unless users of your app are developers with great desire to cooperate.

You can find detailed instructions here:
http://www.cleansoft.lv/debugging-android-applications-remotely/

Comment: Couldn't you do it without port forwarding, by logging in remotely to the user's desktop, and then using adb *on that desktop* to connect to the Android device by USB cable?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Crashlytics](https://docs.fabric.io/android/crashlytics/overview.html) in your app.. It helps you to get the detailed crash logs. Whenever an app crashes, it will send you the detailed crash report, from which you can figure out what is happening at the client side.
Get more info about adding crashlytics to the app from [here](https://fabric.io/kits/android/crashlytics/install).

Send this new app to the client so can have workaround:

Comment: how can the developer test the solution if he-she cannot reproduce it in the local machine?

Answer (score 3):

**Steps to Follow:**

1. First In Android *Settings* Application go to *About Device* option.

   2. Click 9 times on *Build Number* option, so that you can unlock *Developer Options* setting.
   3. Now In you Setting's Application, you will have *Developer Options* enabled, go and click on it.
   4. set following options on : *Stay Awake*, *USB Debugging* and if you have *Internet Adb* option in menu set that also enabled if not then dont worry continue the steps.
   5. Now open your *Android Studio* and the application you want to run on the android device.
   6. In Android Studio, at bottom click on *Terminal* tab, Terminal window opens.
   7. Now through your terminal go to the directory where your *Android SDK* is stored
   8. In SDK directory go to *platform-tools* directory.
   9. Now if you list the files in the *platform-tools* you will see *adb* there.
   10. Running following Commands.

as an example.

```
adb connect <ip-address-of-your-device>:5555
```

as an example:

```
adb connect 10.10.0.21:5555
```

The terminal should show something like below

```
adb server is out of date. killing...
*daemon started successfully*
connected to 10.10.0.21:5555
```

Now run shell command

```
adb shell
```

you will get the prompt something like this, i my case i used android x86 device for debugging.

```
shell@x86_64:/$
```

Now if you go to the task bar in the android studio and click on *Run* options and then *Run'app'* you will be able to see the device as your *Deployment Target*.

Hope it helps !

Comment: OP said over internet 10.10.0.21 is not a public ip

Answer (score 2):

You can also use adb via tcp ip:

```
adb connect ip:port
```

- Use a remote access (teamviewer or droid apk) to enable debugging in android developer tools.
- In the router where the android is connected remember to create port forwards to the android ip.

In your machine with adb installed do:

```
adb connect public_ip:port
```

After being connected, you can do:

```
adb logcat
```

or

```
adb shell
```

Or any adb command you want to.

Comment: what is the port number?

Answer (score 1):

I have a one solution that make your device remotely available using [remote.it](https://www.remote.it/) .

Follow the below step to debugging your app on internet.

**Step 1:**
Download remote.it app from app store.
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.remoteit

**Step 2:**
Sign up into app and follow the steps same as screenshots.

[image]

**Step 3:**
open app.remote.it panel and follow the steps.

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Step 4:**
connect your remote device using adb.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try Debugging Firefox for Android over Wifi it's working with me

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Remote_Debugging/Debugging_Firefox_for_Android_over_Wifi

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).