# Android Remote Debugging

Tags: android, debugging, android-studio, adb, remote-access

I am developing an app that is supposed to communicate with a system with ble chip, but unfortunately the system is not directly available to me but its in another city.

Whenever I need to test something I upload the new apk for even a very small change and the person on the remote location test it.

Is there anyway I can setup a remote debugging environment using android studio / adb that can directly deploy apk to remote android device connected to a laptop may be

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604727/how-can-i-connect-to-android-with-adb-over-tcp) might help. I am not sure if you can use this solution with a VPN, you need to check that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Debugging android device over the Internet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11062629/debugging-android-device-over-the-internet)