# Debug Android application remotely over same vpn

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, remote-debugging

I've developed an Android application which worked fine on my side but failed (not crash) on client side.
I do the research but still can't figure how to do.

From this post [Debugging android device over the Internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11062629/debugging-android-device-over-the-internet)

I know it can achieved by using abd, but it required both pc connect on the same network, which are not suitable for my case where my client are connect on difference network.

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53524186/is-it-possible-to-debug-an-app-with-a-device-connected-on-a-remote-network) suggest another solution which is port forward, but warmed not recommended as this was pretty dangerous.

The following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27245597/how-can-i-deploy-and-execute-an-application-on-a-device-connected-to-a-remote-sy) suggest method of `adb -a -P 5037 nodaemon server`  but I'm not really understand does it work for my situation as i getting error of  `could not install *smartsocket* listener: cannot bind to 0.0.0.0:5037: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted. (10048)`

My question is how do remotely debug (get the logcat) of client application under difference network but was able to connect on the same VPN. Thanks.

Comment: Does the client have a PC that `adb` and perhaps `scrcpy` can be installed into and you remote into that client PC?

Comment: waiting reply from client. May I know is any suggestion if client can/cannot install the adb/scrcpy?

Comment: client only have personal PC, think not really like to install the adb/scrcpy =(

Comment: If failure not a crash, create special app for client which logs everything to file and have client video self interacting with app. Have client send you log and video. Without reproduction steps problem can't be solved.

Comment: why not add a crash reporting service ? it doesn't have to be crashlytics

Comment: @MorrisonChang found a laptop for client which can install adb/scrpy, may I how to setup for collect the logcat?

Comment: @a_local_nobody the app doesn't crash, just not perform as expected result

Comment: fair enough, your question would still be valid regardless, that was merely an alternative suggestion

Comment: @user2301281 I would double check with client that they tried it on a different network (office networks have firewalls). You are trying to remote desktop into the client PC which should be connected to client mobile device. A firewall might prevent you from logging into laptop. From there install `adb`/`scrcpy` (heck even Android Studio if possible) on laptop and then proceed. You will still need to interact with client to approve debug mode on mobile device and understand what about client environment (firewall?) is different than expectations. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Even i had faced the similar problem and [this blog](https://techblogs.42gears.com/how-we-solved-the-challenge-of-remotely-providing-devices-for-devops-employee-onboarding-and-customer-support/) talks on same thing and there is some solution already out there which can be used for working on remote android devices, it looks paid one though.